# PyCharm doesn't identify 'config', Pycharm 2020.3.3 Python 3.9

Tags: python, pycharm, python-3.9

I found this help command from GitHub and put it in my code. I checked all errors and under those errors was the error that `config` was not defined. How do I fix it?

Link to GitHub:
https://gist.github.com/nonchris/1c7060a14a9d94e7929aa2ef14c41bc2

Code (it's a long code, I know):

```
import discord
from discord.ext import commands
from discord.errors import Forbidden

"""This custom help command is a perfect replacement for the default one on any Discord Bot written in Discord.py!
However, you must put "bot.remove_command('help')" in your bot, and the command must be in a cog for it to work.
Original concept by Jared Newsom (AKA Jared M.F.)
[Deleted] https://gist.github.com/StudioMFTechnologies/ad41bfd32b2379ccffe90b0e34128b8b
Rewritten and optimized by github.com/nonchris
https://gist.github.com/nonchris/1c7060a14a9d94e7929aa2ef14c41bc2
You need to set three variables to make that cog run.
Have a look at line 51 to 56
"""


async def send_embed(ctx, embed):
    """
    Function that handles the sending of embeds
    -> Takes context and embed to send
    - tries to send embed in channel
    - tries to send normal message when that fails
    - tries to send embed private with information abot missing permissions
    If this all fails: https://youtu.be/dQw4w9WgXcQ
    """
    try:
        await ctx.send(embed=embed)
    except Forbidden:
        try:
            await ctx.send("Hey, seems like I can't send embeds. Please check my permissions :)")
        except Forbidden:
            await ctx.author.send(
                f"Hey, seems like I can't send any message in {ctx.channel.name} on {ctx.guild.name}\n"
                f"May you inform the server team about this issue? :slight_smile: ", embed=embed)


class Help(commands.Cog):
    """
    Sends this help message
    """

    def __init__(self, bot):
        self.bot = bot

    @commands.command()
    # @commands.bot_has_permissions(add_reactions=True,embed_links=True)
    async def help(self, ctx, *input):
        """Shows all modules of that bot"""
    
    # !SET THOSE VARIABLES TO MAKE THE COG FUNCTIONAL!
        prefix = # ENTER YOUR PREFIX - loaded from config, as string or how ever you want!
    
    # setting owner name - if you don't wanna be mentioned remove line 49-60 and adjust help text (line 88) 
    owner =     # ENTER YOU DISCORD-ID
    owner_name =    # ENTER YOUR USERNAME#1234

        # checks if cog parameter was given
        # if not: sending all modules and commands not associated with a cog
        if not input:
            # checks if owner is on this server - used to 'tag' owner
            try:
                owner = ctx.guild.get_member(config.OWNER).mention

            except AttributeError as e:
                owner = config.OWNER_NAME

            # starting to build embed
            emb = discord.Embed(title='Commands and modules', color=discord.Color.blue(),
                                description=f'Use `{prefix}help <module>` to gain more information about that module '
                                            f':smiley:\n')

            # iterating trough cogs, gathering descriptions
            cogs_desc = ''
            for cog in self.bot.cogs:
                cogs_desc += f'`{cog}` {self.bot.cogs[cog].__doc__}\n'

            # adding 'list' of cogs to embed
            emb.add_field(name='Modules', value=cogs_desc, inline=False)

            # integrating trough uncategorized commands
            commands_desc = ''
            for command in self.bot.walk_commands():
                # if cog not in a cog
                # listing command if cog name is None and command isn't hidden
                if not command.cog_name and not command.hidden:
                    commands_desc += f'{command.name} - {command.help}\n'

            # adding those commands to embed
            if commands_desc:
                emb.add_field(name='Not belonging to a module', value=commands_desc, inline=False)

            # setting information about author
            emb.add_field(name="About", value=f"The Bots is developed by Chriѕ#0001, based on discord.py.\n\
                                    This version of it is maintained by {owner}\n\
                                    Please visit https://github.com/nonchris/discord-fury to submit ideas or bugs.")
            emb.set_footer(text=f"Bot is running {config.VERSION}")

        # block called when one cog-name is given
        # trying to find matching cog and it's commands
        elif len(input) == 1:

            # iterating trough cogs
            for cog in self.bot.cogs:
                # check if cog is the matching one
                if cog.lower() == input[0].lower():

                    # making title - getting description from doc-string below class
                    emb = discord.Embed(title=f'{cog} - Commands', description=self.bot.cogs[cog].__doc__,
                                        color=discord.Color.green())

                    # getting commands from cog
                    for command in self.bot.get_cog(cog).get_commands():
                        # if cog is not hidden
                        if not command.hidden:
                            emb.add_field(name=f"`{config.PREFIX}{command.name}`", value=command.help, inline=False)
                    # found cog - breaking loop
                    break

            # if input not found
            # yes, for-loops have an else statement, it's called when no 'break' was issued
            else:
                emb = discord.Embed(title="What's that?!",
                                    description=f"I've never heard from a module called `{input[0]}` before :scream:",
                                    color=discord.Color.orange())

        # too many cogs requested - only one at a time allowed
        elif len(input) > 1:
            emb = discord.Embed(title="That's too much.",
                                description="Please request only one module at once :sweat_smile:",
                                color=discord.Color.orange())

        else:
            emb = discord.Embed(title="It's a magical place.",
                                description="I don't know how you got here. But I didn't see this coming at all.\n"
                                            "Would you please be so kind to report that issue to me on github?\n"
                                            "https://github.com/nonchris/discord-fury/issues\n"
                                            "Thank you! ~Chris",
                                color=discord.Color.red())

        # sending reply embed using our own function defined above
        await send_embed(ctx, emb)


def setup(bot):
    bot.add_cog(Help(bot))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A config.py file is a file you use to set configurations to your code easily. On the code you sent, it's used to identify a couple of key attributes.
If the original creator hasn't posted the config.py on the github, you can probably do it yourself. First, you will create a .py fle named config, and then you will write on there the attributes that this code calls using config. For example, in one part of the code, we have this:

```
except AttributeError as e:
                owner = config.OWNER_NAME
```

That means the code is going after the config file to look for the attribute "OWNER_NAME", so, when you create your config.py file on your own folder, you will have to define this attribute, with something like:

```
OWNER_NAME = "your name or something"
```

The same goes for every other attribute called through the config.
After you finish defining all of this, make sure the config.py file goes inside the same folder that your code is located, and put on your code this simple line:

```
import config
```

And then your code should run.